# PHP parse Mailgun Webhook message-headers

Tags: php, json, webhooks

I have found many threads about Mailgun json response here but none answers my question

Mailgun returns this string as part of a webhook POST request:

```
[["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with SMTP mgrt 8734663311733; Fri, 03 May 
2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Content-Type", ["multipart/alternative", {"boundary": 
"eb663d73ae0a4d6c9153cc0aec8b7520"}]], ["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Subject", 
"Test bounces webhook"], ["From", "Bob <bob@domain.com.cz>"], ["To", "Alice 
<alice@example.com>"], ["Message-Id", " 
<20130503182626.18666.16540@domain.com>"], ["List-Unsubscribe", "
<mailto:u+na6tmy3ege4tgnldmyytqojqmfsdembyme3tmy3cha4wcndbgaydqyrgoi6wszdpovr
hi5dinfzw63tfmv4gs43uomstimdhnvqws3bomnxw2jtuhusteqjgmq6tm@example.com>"], ["X- 
Mailgun-Sid", "WyIwNzI5MCIsICJhbGljZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsICI2Il0="], ["X-Mailgun- 
Variables", "{"my_var_1": "Mailgun Variable #1", "my-var-2": "awesome"}"], 
["Date", "Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Sender", "bob@domain.com"]]
```

The question is, how to parse it using PHP? `json_decode` returns null. I need to get Subject from that string. Thanks

This is the full response I get:

```
[
attachment-count => 1,
code => 550,
domain => "domain.com",
error => "5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at5.1.1 http://support.example.com/mail/bin/answer.py",
event => "bounced",
message-headers => "[["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with SMTP mgrt 8734663311733; Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Content-Type", ["multipart/alternative", {"boundary": "eb663d73ae0a4d6c9153cc0aec8b7520"}]], ["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Subject", "Test bounces webhook"], ["From", "Bob <bob@domain.com>"], ["To", "Alice <alice@example.com>"], ["Message-Id", "<20130503182626.18666.16540@domain.com>"], ["List-Unsubscribe", "<mailto:u+na6tmy3ege4tgnldmyytqojqmfsdembyme3tmy3cha4wcndbgaydqyrgoi6wszdpovrhi5dinfzw63tfmv4gs43uomstimdhnvqws3bomnxw2jtuhusteqjgmq6tm@lidskasila.cz>"], ["X-Mailgun-Sid", "WyIwNzI5MCIsICJhbGljZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsICI2Il0="], ["X-Mailgun-Variables", "{"my_var_1": "Mailgun Variable #1", "my-var-2": "awesome"}"], ["Date", "Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Sender", "bob@domain.com.cz"]]",
Message-Id => "<20130503182626.18666.16540@lidskasila.cz>",
recipient => "alice@example.com",
signature => "0359cb85c5b22e8de04232f74a77b94d41dc539e0c64034f6787562648bf638c",
timestamp => 1457955019,
token => "cd5808bd17b3523cbbd18426841cec0e0c897d4c325d2c9621",
X-Mailgun-Sid => "WyIwNzI5MCIsICJhbGljZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsICI2Il0="
]
```

Comment: Is that the full response or just a part of it? Can you show `var_dump()` output of the request?

Comment: If you get an error while decoding JSON, [find out why](http://php.net/json_last_error). But `"{"my_var_1": "Mailgun Variable #1"` does not look like valid JSON at all...

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JSON but rather an array of arrays, some of which have JSON objects within them. You can loop through the elements and pick out any values you want. I'm not sure if you're using it already or not but this is the official [Mailgun PHP client](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php), it may ease your pain here?

Comment: I thought it's not valid JSON, I was just wondering whether there's a way to process it. In the documentation, they say it's JSON string https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-bounces and I found no one in the Internet having problems with it so I deducted it's my fault. json_last_error says `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR`, obviously not valid :) Mailgun PHP would solve it, but I thought of webhook as more universal solution.

Comment: I don't know if they're a serious company by I'm myself tired of integrating poorly written third-party APIs that generate invalid XML or don't offer proper error handling.

Comment: Me too. This is Rackspace so I though there must be some elegant solution. Well...whatever

Comment: @simPod: Were you able to extract the subject from response? I am very late. Still it might help someone. The webhook response posted above is mailgun's test webhook response.

Comment: @rAzOr no, I think I stopped trying. It was long time ago so I don't remember exactly. But we don't have the future so I suppose I just left it alone... Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that `message-headers` variable has the correct JSON format. As to Mailgun - order of headers preserved. So this is the code for Subject value:

```
$tmp = $_POST['message-headers'];
$data = json_decode($tmp);
$subject = $data[3][1];
```